# Loading a html page inside a webview which contains a webview element

Tags: android, react-native, kotlin, webview, android-webview

I have an android app which has a webview element in its main activity loading an url. Url is pointing to a html web page consisting of a webview element.
The html code that has to be parsed is similar to this -

`<html>`
   `<head> .... </head>`
   `<body>`
       `....`
       `<div style="width: 1108px; height: 1969.78px;">`
           `<div style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">`
              `<webview id="electron-webview" src="..."></webview> // this`
           `</div>`
       `</div>`
       `....`
   `</body>`
`</html>`

I want this webview to be rendered without using iframe. ( i can change the element tag with anything else)

I tried using [Jsoup](https://jsoup.org/) to extract the webview element and injecting the url in a new webview, but then the scripts it needs won't work.

The only restriction i have is that i can not change the whole code in the backend, i can add some conditional statements in the backend to change the webview element name.
I have freedom to build this mobile application using any framework.

The [webview](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/webview-tag) tag is the electron only feature, thus this code works in electron. However i tried to find a way to run electron on mobile but there was no framework or library supporting that.

Comment: It looks that the webview tag of electronjs is quite someting different from Android WebView and deprecated: https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/webview-tag You have not even mentioned electronjs.

Comment: I will add that too. I was using iframe here and added webview only to see if this works in electron or not. Although it works in electron, electron is not helpful with the mobile application.